# OpenCV 3.0 Linker errors in tracker example

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, tracker

I am trying to build and run the tracker example from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/samples/tracker.cpp).

I have compiled OpenCV 3.0 from source and the extra [contrib-repo](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/) without any problems (all in VS2013).
I've set up a new project set the directories appropriately and tried to build it.
I've added the following lib files (and tried many others which do nothing):

- opencv_core300d.lib
- opencv_video300d.lib
- opencv_videoio300d.lib
- opencv_tracking300d.lib
- opencv_highgui300d.lib

I still get the following 2 linker errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::rectangle(class cv::_InputOutputArray const &,class cv::Point_<int>,class cv::Point_<int>,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &,int,int,int)" (?rectangle@cv@@YAXABV_InputOutputArray@1@V?$Point_@H@1@1ABV?$Scalar_@N@1@HHH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl onMouse(int,int,int,int,void *)" (?onMouse@@YAXHHHHPAX@Z)   D:\Work\ProFit\TLD\test project\Test project\Test project\Source.obj    Test project

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::rectangle(class cv::Mat &,class cv::Rect_<int>,class cv::Scalar_<double> const &,int,int,int)" (?rectangle@cv@@YAXAAVMat@1@V?$Rect_@H@1@ABV?$Scalar_@N@1@HHH@Z) referenced in function _main    D:\Work\ProFit\TLD\test project\Test project\Test project\Source.obj    Test project
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything I search for suggests the cv::rectangle should be contained in the core library file!

Thanks

Comment: in 3.0, all the drawing stuff went from core into imgproc

Comment: berak, brilliant! Thanks very, adding that library sorted it out! I was randomly adding lib files hoping it would work but didn't get round to that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy solution, as pointed out by Berak, the core functionality was in imgproc. Adding opencv_imgproc300d.lib to the project sorted it!